# webrtc connection gets disconnected but sound is still on

Tags: webrtc

I have a video chat application using WebRTC. There is a slight problem: Below is my code for oniceconnectionstatechage:

```
connection.oniceconnectionstatechange = function () {
    if (connection.iceConnectionState == 'disconnected' || connection.iceConnectionState == 'closed')
        console.log('connection gone.')
};
```

The problem is that sometimes, when the internet speed is not well, my connection gets disconnected and I see "connection gone" in my console but the sound still stays on. Both sides can hear each other but the video is gone. What can I do to disconnect my connection completely is such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see `connection gone` in your console when the network connection is unstable, as `iceConnectionState` may have the state `disconnected` as

> a transient state, e. g. on a flaky network, that can recover by itself.
>   [(Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState)

It might be  - **this is an assumption** - that in some/many of such cases video is dropped as the available bandwidth can't support both audio and video.

If you really want to close the connection completely when a disconnect occurs, you can replace your if-statement (incl. the *console.log*) in *oniceconnectionchange* listerner with the following code:

```
if (connection.iceConnectionState == 'disconnected'){
   console.log('Connection gone. Closing connection.');
   connection.close();
}
```

So each `disconnect` will be followed by closing the connection completely.

**However, this is probably bad practice:**
Why would you want to close down the whole connection just because there are temporary problems with the network?
I assume that using this code in a real application will lead to bad user experience, as disconnects will appear in many cases the user would not notice otherwise. I suggest it is better to display a warning to the user in case of (frequent) disconnects.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem but what you said about the problem makes sense and I'm gonna change my code. I think you are right and this is not good practice; so, I'll probably change it too. Thank you very much for your complete answer.